# react-chartjs-2 (chart.js) Radar - Remove values?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

Photo here[Radar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWqwI.png) [Radarcode1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trpkB.png) [Radarcode 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx6q6.png)

Hello everyone, i would like to remove the values on my radar from react-chartjs-2 (for example 2.03 or 3.21), it's ugly and makes my radar hard to read. I tried so many things, i am a bit lost now.

Comment: Please don't post code as images. You can include the code as text between code tags. Makes it a lot easier for other people to work with.

Answer (score 0):

put this (`.map((el) => (Math.round(el)))`) behind your data array so you only get rounded values